# How do kitesurfers / kiteboarders move?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, kinematics, everyday-life

Explanations I've managed to find on the web either focus on how to practice the sport or how a kite flies. A full force vector decomposition that makes clear how downwind, upwind, and crosswind movement is possible as well as when it fails, e.g. kite angle of attack angle for turbulent flow / stable board inclination, would be very helpful.

Fun fact: Given how popular the sport has become, I'm a bit surprised that the keywords `kitesurf` `kitesurfing` and `kiteboard` `kiteboarding` produce 0 results here.

Comment: A kite is like a sail that is rather difficult to "sheet in" or "sheet out" .  Otherwise, the dynamics are very close to a heavily curved sail, and of course the keel/daggerboard size and angle matter.